# Showing text with large font on iPhone

Tags: iphone, accessibility

I'm fine with the size of text on my iPhone. But sometimes I need to show a word or phrase to people whose eyesight isn't as good as mine.

I tried using the standard gesture for zooming in while using the "Notes" application, but it doesn't do anything.

How can I show a piece of text at a large size to someone else?

The approach needs to be able to handle non-alphabetic characters, especially Chinese characters.

Answer (score 2):

Pretty simple, and it will zoom anything on the screen, not just text, so that's even better.

**On your iPhone go to Settings > General > Accessibility > Zoom > Click to turn on.**

See my attached screenshot for a few more commands while zoomed in.

[image: iPhone 5 Zoom]

Answer (score 1):

I apologize because I don't have an iPhone to reference right now, but I will try to help. If you enter your settings and navigate to the accessibility settings, there should be an option to allow screen zooming (or something similar to that name). This is different from regular zooming for two reasons - one, the screen can be zoomed anywhere on the phone - home screen, lock screen, any app - anywhere at any time. And two, when zooming to it is almost like viewing the piece of the screen up close - it will look a bit fuzzy (It doesn't render out), but it is perfectly legible. This is difficult to describe but you will understand what I mean once you use it. You can zoom very far in as well. It can be used by performing some sort of gesture with the fingers (it is a three finger double tap on the iPad). I apologize if this was confusing in any way, however I hope it was what you're looking for. If you can find the setting under the accessibility tab but are still unsure as to how to use it, a quick Google search of the setting will prove very useful. Have a good day!